# Issues making Angular 7, Angular-Material, Node, Express, Sequelize-Typescript and Postgres work together

Tags: angular, postgresql, express, angular-material, sequelize-typescript

I have setup a project using Angular 7 (CLI 7.3.9) and Angular Material for the front-end, NodeJS (10.14.1), Express (4.16.0) and Sequelize-Typescript (1.0.0-beta.3). The database is Postgres (4.6). I have created the backend to access the database with Node and Express and that works (tested with Postman). I have also setup a model with Sequelize-Typescript. The front-end with Angular 7 and Material also works in itself. But I have issues making this all work together and it looks like it's caused by the compile target.

I have tried different settings for target in tsconfig.json: "es5" and "es6". But when I use es5, my back-end breaks when requesting data through Sequelize from Postgres (see errors below). When I set the compile target to es6 my front-end breaks.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "target": "es6",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

With target set to "es5" when requesting data from the database, I get this error at the back-end:

```
TypeError: Class constructor Model cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new Company (C:\Users\snleka\My Projects\hpms-ng2\src\app\server\models\Company.ts:8:42)
    at Function.build (C:\Users\snleka\My Projects\hpms-ng2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2156:12)
    at Function.Model.(anonymous function) (C:\Users\snleka\My Projects\hpms-ng2\node_modules\sequelize-typescript\dist\model\model\model.js:116:28)
```

With the target set to "es6" the front-end breaks with this error message:

```
core.js:19866 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

How can I make front- and back-end work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node relies on es6, however browser support for es6 varies.... You have two options, the first, which I would recommend is to have separate tsConfigs for your front end and back end. If you don't to do that, another option would be to keep your tsConfig set to es6, but to add the babel-loader to your webpack config, so all your front end code once transpiled by typescript to es6, would then get transpiled by babel to es5. I highly recommend having separate tsConfigs though, since webpack will consume the tsConfig for the front end, but the back end will be transpiled separately.

Comment: I'll investigate. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have decided to take a different approach and stop using Sequelize entirely. I have now created my own back-end database queries to Postgres and that works like a charm. Other advantage is that I can make complex queries with SQL and am not limited to the capabilities of Sequelize (in case there are any).

Answer (score 0):

In `tsconfig.json` file use:

```
"target": "es5",
```

and create a new file in your project directory named `.jshintrc` and write the following in it:

```
 { "esversion": 6 }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately not for me